# How can I install ROM on SD-card?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I'm searching the Internet and xda-developers, but they all have tutorials to flash ROM on the device itself; I'm afraid that would brick my device, especially that it would destroy the original ROM.

Is there a way to flash the ROM on an SD-card?

My deivce is Samsung Galaxy Note 2, and I'm looking for Cyanogenmod (maybe CyanogenMod 14.1 ROM, as in [here](https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/news/galaxy-note-2-n7100-android-121836573.html))

Comment: Booting from SD-card is a special feature that has to be supported by the boot-loader. I don't know any Android smartphone that ships with such a boot-loader.

Comment: Is it safe to follow that article, to flash ROM on device directly?

Comment: Changing the device from a factory to a custom ROM means you loose all data. Therefore the major "threats" are that the new ROM does not work as expected or you brick your device. The latter happens very seldom; that you are not happy with the new ROM and wants to switch back to the factory ROM can happen. Therefore make sure you have an original factory ROM image file for your excact device version that you can flash just in case.